# Filter tuples by using value pairs from other table in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, **Friend** (F) and **Likes** (L). **Friend** represents pairs of students (ID1, ID2) who are friends. Friendship is mutual, so if (1510, 1381) is in the **Friend** table, so is (1381, 1510). **Likes** stands for pairs of students ID1 who likes students ID2. Liking someone however is not necessarily reciprocal, so if (1381, 1510) is in the **Likes** table, there is no guarantee that (1510, 1381) is also present.

This is the SQL code to generate both tables:

```
create table Friend(ID1 int, ID2 int);
create table Likes(ID1 int, ID2 int);

insert into Friend values (1510, 1381);
insert into Friend values (1501, 1247);
insert into Friend values (1468, 1641);
insert into Friend values (1641, 1468);
insert into Friend values (1101, 1641);
insert into Friend values (1247, 1911);
insert into Friend values (1641, 1101);
insert into Friend values (1247, 1501);
insert into Friend values (1911, 1247);
insert into Friend values (1381, 1510);
insert into Friend select ID2, ID1 from Friend;

insert into Likes values(1689, 1709);
insert into Likes values(1911, 1247);
insert into Likes values(1641, 1468);
insert into Likes values(1316, 1304);
insert into Likes values(1501, 1934);
```

I want to get pairs (ID1, ID2) in table **Likes** which are NOT included in table **Friend**. The desired output would be this one:

```
ID1     ID2
1689    1709
1316    1304
1501    1934
```

I have just got rid of pairs (1911, 1247) and (1641, 1468).

My quick try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM Likes L, Friend F
WHERE L.ID1 <> F.ID1 AND L.ID1 <> F.ID2 AND L.ID2 <> F.ID1 AND L.ID2 <> F.ID2
```

Which query would give me the desired output? Any idea? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a `left join`, so that all rows of likes are preserved but are associated with `null` if no matching row is found on `friends`. This way you can filter on those nulls to get the rows you need

```
select  L.*
from    likes L
left join
        friends F
on      L.ID1 = F.ID1 and
        L.ID2 = F.ID2
where   F.ID1 is null
```

Comment: Great! That's the answer I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You want all rows for which no corresponding row exists in the other table; this translates into a [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub):

```
SELECT *
FROM Likes
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM Friends
                  WHERE Friends.ID1 = Likes.ID1
                    AND Friends.ID2 = Likes.ID2);
```

But if you are selecting no other columns than the ones you are comparing, i.e., if you are comparing entire rows, then the simplest way to do this is with a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound):

```
SELECT ID1, ID2 FROM Likes
EXCEPT
SELECT ID1, ID2 FROM Friends;
```

Comment: Wow! Those answers are even simpler (and hence better). Both work perfectly for my case. Many thanks @CL.